# How do I make python encrypt both uppercase and lowercase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, case-sensitive, encryption

Basically I want the ciphered phrase as the output with both uppercase being ciphered to uppercase and lowercase being ciphered to lowercase but not any spaces or symbols are ciphered. It can encrypt a paragraph consisting of all upper case and a paragraph consisting of all lower case but not a mix of the two.  here is what I have.

```
def encrypt(phrase,move):
encription=[]
for character in phrase:
    a = ord(character)
    if a>64 and a<123:
        if a!=(91,96):
            for case in phrase:
                        if case.islower():
                            alph=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n",
                                  "o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
                            dic={}
                            for i in range(0,len(alph)):
                                dic[alph[i]]=alph[(i+move)%len(alph)] 
                                cipherphrase=""  
                            for l in phrase:  
                                if l in dic:  
                                    l=dic[l]  
                                cipherphrase+=l
                                encription.append(chr(a if 97<a<=122 else 96+a%122))
                            return cipherphrase
                        else:
                            ALPH=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N",
                                  "O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
                            DIC={}
                            for I in range(0,len(ALPH)):
                                DIC[ALPH[I]]=ALPH[(I+move)%len(ALPH)]
                                cipherphrase=""
                            for L in phrase:
                                if L in DIC:
                                    L=DIC[L]
                                cipherphrase+=L
                                encription.append(chr(a if 97<a<=122 else 96+a%122))
                            return cipherphrase
```

I know its a lot but as you can see im not very good

Comment: What do you want to happen here? Should lower case letters always be replaced with lower case and vice versa?

Comment: basically yes, i'll go edit the question

Comment: what is your ultimate goal here? do you want to encrypt or *encode*?

Comment: @miraculixx I dont know the difference between encrypt or encode but I do want it to work as a Caesar cipher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import string

def caesar_cipher(msg, shift):
    # create a character-translation table
    trans = dict(zip(string.lowercase, string.lowercase[shift:] + string.lowercase[:shift]))
    trans.update(zip(string.uppercase, string.uppercase[shift:] + string.uppercase[:shift]))

    # apply it to the message string
    return ''.join(trans.get(ch, ch) for ch in msg)
```

then

```
caesar_cipher('This is my 3rd test!', 2)     # => 'Vjku ku oa 3tf vguv!'
```

Comment: I tried this as well, All I got was this
`>>> cr('Hi Ho sivlver, AWAAAY!',1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#111>", line 1, in <module>
    cr('Hi Ho sivlver, AWAAAY!',1)
  File "G:/Algorithms/Python Assignment 2/Q3).py", line 99, in cr
    trans = dict(zip(string.lowercase, string.lowercase[shift:] + string.lowercase[:shift]))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lowercase'`

Comment: never mind got it to work, just needed ascii_lowercase and ascii_uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

```
import string
def rot_cipher(msg,amount):
    alphabet1 = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase
    alphabet2 = string.ascii_lowercase[amount:] + string.ascii_lowercase[:amount]\
                + string.ascii_uppercase[amount:] + string.ascii_uppercase[:amount]
    tab = str.maketrans(alphabet1,alphabet2)
    return msg.translate(tab)

print(rot_cipher("hello world!",13))
```

Comment: tried using it, kept getting this
`>>> rot_cipher('Hi ho silver, AWAAAYY!!',1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#110>", line 1, in <module>
    rot_cipher('Hi ho silver, AWAAAYY!!',1)
  File "G:/Algorithms/Python Assignment 2/Q3).py", line 92, in rot_cipher
    tab = string.maketrans(alphabet1,alphabet2)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'`

Comment: hmmm they may have done away with it in python 3 gimme a minute to figure out what they changed it to

Comment: looks like in python3 you can use `str.maketrans`  edited solution to use this...